# Como separar elementos en HTML ademas del &nbsp;?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un bloc de notas en react-native, no tiene nada que ver con html, pero hay un metodo que utiliza html, por eso la pregunta, resulta que mediante este metodo llamado insertHTML, puedo mediante parametros insertar HTML, el problema es que como es un bloc de notas, si yo inserto un `<p>`, el cursor (palito que sirve para escribir) no entra al `<p>`, por lo que esta insertado pero no puedo escribir en el, imprimiendo en consola esta estructura:

```
texto <p></p>
```

la unica forma de que al insertar el elemento y poder escribir dentro de el una vez insertado, es si le pongo `&nbsp;` en el `<p>` a la hora de llamar la funcion es decir:

```
insertHMTL(`<p>&nbsp;</p>`);
```

al ejecutar la funcion, ya lo que escriba estara dentro de la etiqueta `<p>`, el problema mio es el siguente, como sabran `&nbsp;` significa non brake space, quiere decir que este no hara salto de linea en los elementos que esten delante de el, si no que los mantendra en la misma linea, es decir: si yo hago esto:

```
insertHTML(`<p>hola</p>&nbsp;<p>como</p>&nbsp;<p>estas</p>`);
```

por el input saldria: `hola como estas` y por la consola esta estructura `<p>hola</p>&nbsp;<p>como</p>&nbsp;<p>estas</p>`

el problema esta cuando yo hago cambios desde el input, y creo nuevos `&nbsp;`, estos no son insertados manualmente por lo que si hacen su funcion ademas de dar espaciado, este es un ejemplo de cual es el problema:

supongamos que la oracion hola como estas, yo quiero hacer que esten juntas algunas palabras, lo que quiero es: hola comoestas, para hacer esto tengo que mover el curso hasta detras de la `e` de estas y hacer backspace, al hacer backspace, estoy eliminado el `&nbsp;` que hay entre como y estas, lo que saldria en la consola:

````
```<p>hola</p>&nbsp;<p>como</p><p>estas</p>```
````

al yo querer separarlos de nuevo, presiono el spacebar entre como y estas, para separarlos.

el tag `<span>` de estas se vuelve un `<font` tag, y el `&nbsp;` es creado dentro de este `<font>` tag, es decir junto a estas y no aparte como deberia ser, en la consola:

````
```<p>hola</p>&nbsp;<p>como</p><font>&nbsp;estas</font>```
````

esto pasa porque el cursor (palito para escribir) al parecer crea esto mediante la ultima letra con la que esta en contacto o con la que esta en contacto actualmente, por lo que como estoy en contacto le `e` yo al hacer space, crea un `&nbsp;` junto a `e`

en pocas palabras, al yo tener palabras juntas y hacer space entre algunas de ellas, las palabras que esten despues de la como de `&nbsp;` se concatenaran, y yo no quiero eso, aqui un ejemplo de lo que acabo de decir:

```
holacomoestas //lo que muestra el input

<span>hola</span><span>como</span><span>estas</span> //lo que muestra la consola

al yo hacer espacio entre hola y como, con estas AUN pegado a como pasa esto:

hola comoestas //lo que muestra el input 

<span>hola</span><font>&nbsp;comoestas</font> //lo que muestra la consola
```

este es mi problema, porque a la hora de yo hacer un nuevo espacio por mi mismo, este inserta el  , y si hay alguna palabra pegada, este lo metera en la misma etiqueta, ya que todo lo que va despues de la ; del `&nbsp;` el lo va a concatenar y los va a juntar, no importa si son etiquetas diferentes etc

espero puedan ayudarme y perdon por la publicacion tan larga :)

Comment: has intentando eliminar las etiquetas al guardar el texto??? y los caracteres especiales??? no se que es lo que necesitas solo el texto??

Comment: No se entiende nada de lo que pretendes, ¿crees que puedas crear un [mcve] para ver el problema? Saludos